# I want to fail Beanshell sampler when my script is not conditions not satisfied

Tags: jmeter

I am using Beanshell sampler with java code  to compare the two files line by line. I want to fail the Beanshell sampler if comparison failed at any line. I see always my beanshell sampler is sucess in view results treee even the comparison failed or passed. So any one please give me a idea how to fail the sampler.

Note: I used Beanshell Assertion as well but its not worked.

[View Results Tree Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59Q32.png)

[Beanshell Sampler with Beanshell Assertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwpU5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean differenceInFile = false;
SampleResult.setSuccessful(differenceInFile);
IsSuccess=differenceInFile;
```

line #2 and line #3 is what you need in your bean shell sampler to pass / fail depending on your file comparasion

[Sample JMX File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rkG3Om5X06XiZL7Mb-6qH1F38B-oiwPk/view?usp=sharing)
It will show you as an xml, try to download it

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) pre-defined variable which you can use for setting the sampler passed or failed, define response code, response message, response body, etc.

So something like:

```
if (there_are_differences) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500")
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Files are different")
}
```

In the assertion you have [AssertionResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/assertions/AssertionResult.html) for the same.

Also be aware that [you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it might be a good option for migration.

More information on [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for the JSR223 Test Elements - [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)